# Sqlalchemy searching dates

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to do a search between two dates with sqlalchemy. If I used static dates will be this way.

```
def secondExercise():
 for instance in session.query(Puppy.name, Puppy.weight, Puppy.dateOfBirth).\
    filter(Puppy.dateOfBirth <= '2015-08-31', Puppy.dateOfBirth >= '2015-02-25'     ).order_by(desc("dateOfBirth")):
 print instance
```

Manipulating dates in python is quite easy.

```
today = date.today().strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
sixthmonth = date(date.today().year, date.today().month-6,date.today().day).strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
```

The problem is, I don't know how to implement this as parameter. Any help with this?

```
for instance in session.query(Puppy.name, Puppy.weight, Puppy.dateOfBirth).\
                  filter(Puppy.dateOfBirth <= today, Puppy.dateOfBirth >= sixthmonth ).order_by(desc("dateOfBirth")):
```

Answer (score 0):

SQLAlchemy supports comparison by datetime.date() and datetime.datetime() objects.
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/type_basics.html?highlight=datetime#sqlalchemy.types.DateTime

You can expose these as parameters (replace your_query with all the stuff you want to be constant and not parametrized):

```
six_months_ago = datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(180)
today = datetime.datetime.today()

def query_puppies(birth_date=six_months_ago):
    for puppy in your_query.filter(Puppy.dateOfBirth.between(birthdate, today)):
       print puppy.name # for example..
```

Also note the usage of the between clause for some extra awesomeness :)
but two seperate clasuses using <= and >= would also work.

cheers